# biblatex-apa generating weird year citations

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I recently changed from `natbib` to `biblatex-apa`, and things are somewhat better - I can cite webpages APA-style - but also worse, because the hookups aren't working properly. They're outputting nothing.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} 

\usepackage[ backend=biber, style=apa ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\label{Bibliography}

\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and my bibliography code:

```
@book{medusa,
  address = {Edinburgh},
  title = {I and thou},
  publisher = {T. \& {T}. {Clark}},
  author = {Buber, Martin},
  translator = {Smith, Ronald Gregor},
  year = {1937},
  related = {test1orig},
  relatedtype = {reprintfrom}
}
```

And my actual output:

> Buber, M. (labelyearlabelmonthlabelday). I and thou (R. G. Smith, Trans.). Edinburgh: T. & 
>   T. Clark. (Repr. from I and thou, by M. Buber, OrigPlace: OrigPublisher)

What's going on here? I've tagged things properly, I think?

Answer (score 6):

In order to use `biblatex-apa` properly you need to load `babel` (or `polyglossia` if you are using XeLaTeX) with the correct language specified and `csquotes`.  Here's an example for British English (which I assume you are using; substitute `american` if not):

```
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
```

See section 3 of the `biblatex-apa` manual for details.

(Your minimal document won't compile for anyone, since you are using a custom class and you have code from other packages in it (`\lhead` from `fancyhdr`)).

Comment: Recent versions of `biblatex-apa` don't need explicit `\DeclareLanguageMapping`s any more. The mappings will be applied automatically for all supported languages.