# (labelyearlabelmonthlabelday) in biblatex-apa bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm having trouble using `biblatex-apa` to create a bibliography. When I run my project through `latexmk`, I get a reference section that looks like this:

> Chan, K., Van Zwieten, L., Meszaros, I., Downie, A., & Joseph, S. (labelyearlabelmonth- labelday). Agronomic values of greenwaste biochar as a soil amendment. Soil Research, 45(8), 629–634.
>
> Rondon, M. A., Lehmann, J., Ram ́ırez, J., & Hurtado, M. (labelyearlabelmonthlabelday). Biological nitrogen fixation by common beans (phaseolus vulgaris l.) increases with bio-char additions. Biology and Fertility of Soils, 43 (6), 699–708.

I took a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145950/biblatex-apa-generating-weird-year-citations) to a similar problem, but none of the suggestions worked for me.

My bibliography file entries look like this:

```
@article{rondon2007biological,
    Author = {Rondon, Marco A and Lehmann, Johannes and Ram{\'\i}rez, Juan and Hurtado, Maria},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-05 23:51:41 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-05 23:51:41 +0000},
    Journal = {Biology and Fertility of Soils},
    Number = {6},
    Pages = {699--708},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Biological nitrogen fixation by common beans (Phaseolus vulgaris L.) increases with bio-char additions},
    Volume = {43},
    Year = {2007},
    }

@article{chan2008agronomic,
    Author = {Chan, KY and Van Zwieten, L and Meszaros, I and Downie, A and Joseph, S},
    Journal = {Soil Research},
    Number = {8},
    Pages = {629--634},
    Publisher = {CSIRO},
    Title = {Agronomic values of greenwaste biochar as a soil amendment},
    Volume = {45},
    Year = {2008},
}
```

My .tex file looks like this (with most of the content removed for conciseness):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,graphicx, url}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{biochar.bib}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \parencite{chan2008agronomic}.
    \parencite{rondon2007biological}
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty new to bib latex, so I'll admit that I could very well be doing something extremely stupid. I'm using TeXLive 2013 on Mac OS X Mavericks, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Either you use `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}` or you use `\usepackage[american]{babel}`.  Currenlty you mix the two.

Comment: Yup, that fixes it. I am not very smart. Thanks!

Comment: @Guido Make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file contains both

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
```

and

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
```

One has to use one of the two options above, not both.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: One has to use (`\usepackage[american]{babel}` and `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`) or (`\usepackage[british]{babel}` and `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}`)?

Comment: Though note that with more recent versions of `biblatex-apa` `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is executed automatically for all supported languages (check the available `.lbx` files at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa). So the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` should not be needed. What one might need is a `<lang>-apa.lbx` in case `biblatex-apa` does not support `<lang>`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use **both** `\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}` and `\DeclareLanguageMapping{indonesian}{indonesian-apa}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{indonesian}{indonesian-apa}
```

if I remove `\DeclareLanguageMapping{indonesian}{indonesian-apa}` then I get problem as you questioned.

I copied `indonesian-apa.lbx` from `british-apa.lbx` file (planning to modify things if necessary, but currently I don't know yet).

P.S.: I use [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com?r=de1ac91d&rm=d&rs=b), which as of Feb 20, 2019 uses `biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)`.

Comment: Welcome. Hmm, I think this is exactly what Guido and moewe stated in his answer.

Comment: In recent versions of `biblatex-apa` you won't need a `\DeclareLanguageMapping` at all, as it it executed automatically. In your case the important/problematic bit is that both `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` don't have an `indonesian` localisation. `biblatex` won't have a lot of trouble with that (everything will just be in English), but `biblatex-apa` *needs* an `.lbx` file because it contains important macros, so you must get an `indonesian-apa.lbx` with the relevant definitions from somewhere (for example by copying an English file as you did).

Comment: @JouleV moewe's comment is clearer, while Guido's is somewhat ambiguous. But yes, this is exactly what moeve's comment stated, but unfortunately his comment is not an answer..

Comment: Overleaf has an outdated version of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` where the mapping is not yet automated, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474557/35864