# Issues with Biblatex and the bib files

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, french

My bibliography codes looks like this

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}
```

And an exemple of one my references

```
  @article{Harrison2007,
  title = {What's the Difference? Diversity Constructs as Separation, Variety, or Disparity in Organizations},
  volume = {32},
  issn = {0363-7425, 1930-3807},
  shorttitle = {What's the Difference?},
  language = {en},
  number = {4},
  journal = {Academy of Management Review},
  doi = {10.5465/amr.2007.26586096},
  author = {Harrison, David A. and Klein, Katherine J.},
  month = oct,
  year = {2007},
  pages = {1199-1228},
  file = {C:\\Users\\ornel\\Zotero\\storage\\RZNS5L26\\Harrison et Klein - 2007 - What's the difference diversity constructs as sep.pdf}
```

And I use this citation style

```
\autocite{Harrison2007}
```

But when I compile overleaf, the citation is not found.

This is the error I get : 
`BibTeX Cannot find 'bibliographie.bib'!`

Comment: Do *any* of your references appear correctly? Do just certain ones fail to be found?

Comment: none of my references appear. It is like  overleaf cannont read my `bib files`

Comment: Do you get an error that says "bibtex cannot find `bibliographie.bib`"?

Comment: If you scroll down past all the orange warnings, is there a red error message as in my previous comment?  Have you tried deleting all the `.aux` files and then recompiling? (use the Trashcan icon in the error logs panel).

Comment: Yes there is the error `BibTeX Cannot find 'bibliographie.bib'!`

Comment: So *that's* the real error. It simply can't find your `.bib` file. So either the file is differently named, or at one point you had a typo in your `\addbibresource` line, and it hasn't updated properly. If that is the case, delete all the `.aux` files (which Overleaf calls *cache* files) and try again.  But until that error is removed, the undefined references are irrelevant, since it can't find the file itself.

Comment: I delete the cache, then copy paste the name of my `bib files` to be sure that I didn't do any typo but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm trying to use biblatex but the message is bibtex , is that the issues ?

Comment: No, that's just a generic error message generated by Overleaf; it should run `biber` automatically.  I'm not really sure we can help you here. This seems like something you should take up with Overleaf support.

Comment: Note that at least in the example posted here the entry `Harrison2007` is missing the closing curly bracket and the end. This might just be a copy-and-paste error, but if it is not it can certainly cause Biber to get the hiccups and discard almost all entries from your `.bib` file. Other than that the entry looks OK and the rest of the code does not give any hints about problems apart from the possibly missing `\DeclareLanguageMapping` (which depends on code you haven't shown). We need to see a full MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) ...

Comment: ... and ideally the `.log` and `.blg` files. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 shows how to download the `.bbl` file, use the same technique to download and inspect the **`.log`** and **`.blg`** files.

Answer (score 2):

Overleaf is running TeXLive 2017, which has an older version of `biblatex-apa`. In this version you need to add the following line to your preamble after you load `biblatex` (since you are writing in French).

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
```

The general syntax is:

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{<lang>}{<lang>-apa}
```

If you are writing in English, you would usually use:

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}
```

See [Problem with \mkbibdateapalongextra of biblatex-apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133700/2693) for more detailed information.

If you had reported the log error, your question would have been easier to answer.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how adding this line will help overleaf find my bib files.  The error I have is `Citation XXX on page XXX undefined on input line XXX`

Comment: I was working from the MWE posted in the answer by RedCloud. That example doesn't compile on Overleaf, so it seemed possible that this was your problem, and the line I give will fix it.  (I assume it's already in your document then.)  Does the sample code given by RedCloud work for you (with this addition)? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your `.bib` entry.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't  work

Comment: @Dosma Please be more helpful with your reports. "It doesn't work" provides no useful information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474557/35864

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any problem with the above bib entry:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{Harrison2007,
    title = {What's the Difference? Diversity Constructs as Separation, Variety, or Disparity in 
    Organizations},
    volume = {32},
    issn = {0363-7425, 1930-3807},
    shorttitle = {What's the Difference?},
    language = {en},
    number = {4},
    journal = {Academy of Management Review},
    doi = {10.5465/amr.2007.26586096},
    author = {Harrison, David A. and Klein, Katherine J.},
    month = oct,
    year = {2007},
    pages = {1199-1228},
    file = {C:\\Users\\ornel\\Zotero\\storage\\RZNS5L26\\Harrison et Klein - 2007 - What's the difference 
    diversity constructs as sep.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

foo~\textcite{Harrison2007}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the first two lines that you put , are they necessary ?\RequirePackage{filecontents} AND 
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}

Comment: Yes. The first one to allow the environment `filecontents` to overwrite the external file `test.bib` if edited. It is here only for testing your bibtex entry. You do not need it if you already have you data file for the bibliography.

Comment: Because my bib files start with a reference

Comment: @Dosma No, they are just used in the example code to make the file self-contained. They should not be in your `.bib` file.

Comment: @Red-Cloud Did you try this on Overleaf? It fails.

Comment: No I didn't use overleaf ...