# biblatex issue when loading babel

Tags: biblatex, babel

I use BibLaTeX to format my professional CV, with several, separate, "refsections" citing my publications.  I recently moved into a new computer and noticed after installing the latest version of MikTeX (v23.10), there appears to be an unfortunate conflict between `biblatex` (2023/03/05 v3.19) and `babel` (2023/09/29 v3.95) that results in the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.25 \end
         {refsection}
```

Here is a MWE that illustrates the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa6,sorting=ydnt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {This is a Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Scholarship}

\begin{refsection}
\nocite{key}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: in a currently system you don't need \DeclareLanguageMapping (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474640/2388) and if I remove it your document compiles.

Comment: How about that!  When I remove the \DeclareLanguageMapping command from my much-more-complex document it also compiles without complaint.  Thank you very much @UlrikeFischer!

Comment: Often the explicit `\DeclareLanguageMapping` with `biblatex-apa`/`biblatex-apa6`, while unnecessary, is not actively harmful. Here it is harmful, because `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` loads `biblatex-apa`'s `.lbx` files, but you are using `biblatex-apa6` so this code forces `biblatex` to load the incorrect localisation files for your style leading to resulting in low-level errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a currently system you don't need `\DeclareLanguageMapping` (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474640/2388 for more details)
and if I remove it your document compiles.